# chrome says Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36

Tags: http-headers, user-agent

I am trying to identify and do some study on what user agent is sending request to our application.

when i execute the request in chrome i see that it says

> "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36"

when i execute it from safari it says

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50

when u execute it from mozilla it says

> Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0

Why does it say "Mozilla/5.0" for all requests and for chrome specifically it lists all mozilla, chrome and safari.

Can any one please explain why is this the case? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

User agent strings are a mess, and it is very difficult to write code to get accurate information from them. (See [this link](http://webaim.org/blog/user-agent-string-history/) for a detailed history of why).

If you just want to gather statistics, try adding Google Analytics to your front end, or use a library that specializes in parsing user agent strings on your back end, such as [MobileDetect](http://mobiledetect.net/) for PHP.

If you want to do something different depending on what features the browser supports, try detecting support for that feature instead of the browser version. [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) is great for this.